# Perl: How to match last n digits of a string with n consecutive digits or more?

Tags: regex, perl

I use the following:

```
if ($content =~ /([0-9]{11})/) {
    my $digits = $1;
}
```

to extract 11 consecutive digits from a string. However, it grabs the first 11 consecutive digits. How can I get it to extract the last 11 consecutive digits so that I  would get `24555199361` from a string with `hdjf95724555199361`?

Comment: Start your pattern with `.*` : any character (except the newline sequence) 0 or more times, greedily (by default).

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte `$content =~ /.*([0-9]{11})/` worked. If you want put it as answer I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
/([0-9]{11})/
```

means

```perl
/^.*?([0-9]{11})/s   # Minimal lead that allows a match.
```

You get what you want by making the `.*` greedy.

```perl
/^.*([0-9]{11})/s    # Maximal lead that allows a match.
```

If the digits appear at the very end of the string, you can also use the following:

```perl
/([0-9]{11})\z/
```

Comment: Note that anchoring isn't that useful with a `.*` unless you have something else going on that you haven't shown. The match already starts at the beginning of the string. tchrist hammered me on that a few times during Programming Perl. :)

Comment: @briandfoy, Re "*The match already starts at the beginning of the string.*", No, not quite. Sure, the first attempt will be at positions 0, but it can backtrack and try again at position 1, then position 2, then position 3, etc. Without `^`, a failed match can go quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to match something at the end of a string, use the end of line anchor `$`.

```perl
$content =~ m/(\d{11})$/;
```

If that pattern is not the very end, but you want to match the "last" occurence of that pattern, you would first match "the entire string" with `/.*/` and then backtrack to the final occurence of the pattern.  The `/s` flag permits the `.` metacharacter to match a line feed.

```perl
$content =~ m/.*(\d{11})/s;
```

See the [Perl regexp tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for more information.

Comment: Re "*Whenever you want to match something at the end of a string, use the end of line anchor `$`.*",  No, use `\z`. That's not what `$` does.

Comment: Re "*`m/.*(\d{11})/s`*", No. As the previous answer showed, you want a leading `\A` (or `^` if /m isn't used) to avoid needless backtracking on a failed match